# Confusion about different file modes

Tags: c, file-io

If I open a (say) binary file, and I want to append the end of it both of the following ways seem to work for me

```
fileVar = fopen("FileName", "w+b");
```

and

```
fileVar = fopen("FileName", "r+b");
```

I have read the documentation, but I'm not clear about the difference between these two methods of opening the file. [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) website says that `w+` will overwrite a file if it doesn't exist already, and `a+` will append to the end of the file. I haven't tried using `a+`, but it seems to do the same thing as `r+`.

**Question:** What exactly is the difference between the three ways of opening a file, `r+`, `w+` and `a+`?

Comment: pretty sure the [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fopen/) lays it out clear as day.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58419418/12114801

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**r+** starts at beginning of file, but will not create a new file if it doesn't exists.

**w+** truncates existing file to zero length if the file exists, otherwise creates a new file.

**a+** starts at end of file if file exists, otherwise creates a new file.

*Access modes r+, w+ and a+ opens the file in read and write mode, but with the above difference:*

Both r+ and w+ we can read ,write on file but r+ does not truncate  (delete) the content of file  as well it doesn’t create a new file if such file doesn’t exits while in w+ truncate the content of file as well as create a new file if such file doesn’t exists.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the website says:

- `r+` will open the file for reading & writing, but the file **must** exist.
- `w+` will open the file for reading & writing, but if the file exists it will truncate the file (remove its contents).
- `a+` will open the file for reading & writing, but while reading is allowed at any location, you can only write to the end of the file, i.e. append.