# Difference between r+ and w+ in fopen()

Tags: c, fopen

In `fopen("myfile", "r+")` what is the difference between the `"r+"` and `"w+"` open mode? I read this:

> `"r"`   Open a text file for reading. 
> `"w"` Open a text file for writing,
>   truncating an an existing file to zero length, or creating the file if it does not exist.
>
> `"r+"` Open a text file for update (that is, for both reading and
>   writing). 
> `"w+"` Open a text file for update (reading and writing),
>   first truncating
>       the file to zero length if it exists or creating the file if it does not    exist.

I mean the difference is that if I open the file with `"w+"`, the file will be erased first?

Comment: the 2 differences are right there: truncating and creating.

Comment: ... it will be "erased" first, or created if it does not exist (while `r+` would give error in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between modes a, a+, w, w+, and r+ in built-in open function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r-in-built-in-open-function)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The main difference is `w+` truncate the file to zero length if it exists or create a new file if it doesn't. While `r+` neither deletes the content nor create a new file if it doesn't exist.

Try these codes and you will understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   FILE *fp;

   fp = fopen("test.txt", "w+");
   fprintf(fp, "This is testing for fprintf...\n");
   fputs("This is testing for fputs...\n", fp);
   fclose(fp);
}
```

and then this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   FILE *fp;

   fp = fopen("test.txt", "w+");
   fclose(fp);
}
```

If you will open `test.txt`, you will see that all data written by the first program has been erased.
Repeat this for `r+` and see the result.
Here is the summary of different file modes:

[image]

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 96):

Both `r+` and `w+` can read and write to a file. However, `r+` doesn't delete the content of the file and doesn't create a new file if such file doesn't exist, whereas `w+` deletes the content of the file and creates it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I was searching for a way to not delete the contents of the file (like r+) but also create a new file if it doesn't exist (like w+).  I discovered `open(x, 'a').close(); open(x, 'r+')`

Answer (score 84):

Here is a quick reference diagram showing how to choose a file mode:

[image: Flow Diagram for fopen controls]

Note that `a+`, `w`, and `w+` modes will create a new file if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Just found out that "a" does not allow seeking for writing. Documentation for "a+" states "output is always appended to the end of the file", and so it may hold true for "a".

Comment: So no difference between a and a+
Both are for wrirting bowth are not for truncating both initial position is at end.

Comment: @Irtza Shahan Not exactly the same, all you said is correct. But, in addition to that, you can also use "a+" to read content of the file. You may think that it makes no sense due to initial position is End, but remember you can move the pointer afterwards.

Answer (score 25):

```
r = read mode only
r+ = read/write mode
w = write mode only
w+ = read/write mode, if the file already exists override it (empty it)
```

So yes, if the file already exists w+ will erase the file and give you an empty file.

Answer (score 6):

**w+**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("test.txt", "w+");  //write and read mode
   fprintf(fp, "This is testing for fprintf...\n"); 

   rewind(fp); //rewind () function moves file pointer position to the beginning of the file.
   char ch;
   while((ch=getc(fp))!=EOF)
   putchar(ch);

   fclose(fp);
}
```

output

```
This is testing for fprintf...
```

test.txt

```
This is testing for fprintf...
```

---

**w** and **r** to form **w+**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   FILE *fp;

   fp = fopen("test.txt", "w"); //only write mode
   fprintf(fp, "This is testing for fprintf...\n"); 
   fclose(fp);
   fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
   char ch;
   while((ch=getc(fp))!=EOF)
   putchar(ch);
   fclose(fp);
}
```

output

```
This is testing for fprintf...
```

test.txt

```
This is testing for fprintf...
```

---

**r+**

test.txt

```
This is testing for fprintf...
```

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r+");  //read and write mode
    char ch;
    while((ch=getc(fp))!=EOF)
    putchar(ch);
    rewind(fp); //rewind () function moves file pointer position to the beginning of the file.
    fprintf(fp, "This is testing for fprintf again...\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
This is testing for fprintf...
```

test.txt

```
This is testing for fprintf again...
```

---

**r** and **w** to form **r+**

test.txt

```
This is testing for fprintf...
```

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r"); 
    char ch;
    while((ch=getc(fp))!=EOF)
    putchar(ch);
    fclose(fp);

    fp=fopen("test.txt","w");
    fprintf(fp, "This is testing for fprintf again...\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
This is testing for fprintf...
```

test.txt

```
This is testing for fprintf again...
```

---

**a+**

test.txt

```
This is testing for fprintf...
```

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "a+");  //append and read mode
    char ch;
    while((ch=getc(fp))!=EOF)
    putchar(ch);
    rewind(fp); //rewind () function moves file pointer position to the beginning of the file.
    fprintf(fp, "This is testing for fprintf again...\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
This is testing for fprintf...
```

test.txt

```
This is testing for fprintf...
This is testing for fprintf again...
```

---

**a** and **r** to form **a+**

test.txt

```
This is testing for fprintf...
```

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "a");  //append and read mode
    char ch;
    while((ch=getc(fp))!=EOF)
    putchar(ch);
    fclose(fp);
    fp=fopen("test.txt","r");
    fprintf(fp, "This is testing for fprintf again...\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
This is testing for fprintf...
```

test.txt

```
This is testing for fprintf...
This is testing for fprintf again...
```

Comment: Best answer in my humble opinion. Should be the accepted one.

Comment: What happens to the text file opened in r+ mode if the string printed in the example above is shorter than what is in the initial test.text. for example fprintf (fp, "Hello"); does it become simply Hello or Hellois testing fprintf again...

Comment: @Janjan It prints Hello

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 differences, unlike `r+`, `w+` will:

- create the file if it does not already exist
- first truncate it, i.e., will delete its contents

Answer (score 0):

r+ The existing file is opened to the beginning for both reading and writing. 
w+ Same as w except both for reading and writing.