# Python writing/Modifying MBR

Tags: python, python-2.7, overwrite, disk

I'm working on a programme to modify the MBR. The thing is i can open it with.

```
a = open(r"\\.\PhysicalDisk0", "r+b")
a.write("data")
```

The code dosent shows any errors and when I read the MBR again it doesn't show the data I wrote. Any solutions?

Comment: isn't that a tad dangerous?

Comment: @roganjosh it will write: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113919/difference-between-r-and-w-in-fopen. `r+b` is not r and b. It's `r+` and binary: "r+" Open a text file for update (that is, for both reading and writing).

Comment: @Jean I stand corrected

Comment: are you sure the code runs without exceptions? are you running this as an administrator? doesn't antivirus software protect from those? oh you're not using windows by linux right?

Comment: @roganjosh I don't blame you. I spent 2 hours the other day trying to open a file in read/write using `"rw"` :)